# Scheduler controls

Tags: wpf, controls, scheduler

I need to implement "appointments diary" features in my WPF application so am needing a decent Scheduler control. Has anyone experience of all the main players scheduling components(DevExpress/C1/Telerik/Infragistics) and can offer a quick comparison? App is MVVM, don't know if this would hinder any suite in particular?

Comment: You can build that kind of control yourself easily with WPF. Please take a look at my answer to the [Looking for a outlook calendar type control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197905/looking-for-a-outlook-calendar-type-control/21198066#21198066) question for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used DevExpress, C1, and Telerik's scheduling controls before. I find DevExpress to have the most polished, more feature-packed, and better performing of the 3. Their WPF Scheduler control is very good.

Overall I find that DevExpress components are very flexible and I've used MVVM with them many times.